# Powerapps - Pick "Title" text from Browse screen and add it as default to Form screen dropdown Options

Tags: sharepoint-2013, default, dropdown, powerapps

I am creating an app with 3 screens -

1. Home screen - normal text based screen with two buttons -
   View All-All Records Gallery. The items for this gallery are coming from SP List1
   FormScreen - Form which submits data into SP List2
2. ViewAll Screen - This contains gallery with Title, Subtitle, Body and
   Navigation arrow. Data for this gallery is coming from SP List2.
   Clicking on the arrow should navigate to FormScreen
3. FormScreen - This has data source as SP List2

I wanted to pass "Title" value from ViewAll screen and set it as default for dropdown on FormScreen once I click on the Navigate arrow.

I do not have EditScreen/EditForm. If I directly come from HomeScreen to the FormScreen the form should open in new mode with no defaults set for the dropdown but if I am coming from ViewAll screen to the FormScreen then it should pick up the Title value and set it as a default for one of the dropdown control on FormScreen.

So far I have tried setting the global variables but no luck -

```
Navigate(FormScreen, transition.fade, {myValue:ThisItem.Title})
```

To debug this issue I added a temporary text input on the FormScreen and have set its Text property to myValue and it works fine but with dropdown it is not showing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you got Title value in your DropDown, if you want to add this to  DropDown you have to use collection.

**Home Screen** - ***OnVisible*** event: `Set(myDefaultDropDownValue, "")`

**Navigation arrow** ***OnSelect*** event: `Set(myDefaultDropDownValue, Title.Text)`

**DropDown** on **FormScreen** Default value: `myDefaultDropDownValue`

Comment: you're AWESOME!! Thanks a lot.